# Is there hidden data in the iris.csv dataset that comes with sklearn?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

Apologies for the noobish question...

I'm playing around with the iris dataset that comes with sklearn. When I enter:

```
iris.feature_names
```

It outputs:

```
['sepal length (cm)',
 'sepal width (cm)',
 'petal length (cm)',
 'petal width (cm)']
```

What I don't understand is where it's getting those words. I opened the iris CSV in Excel and I cannot find any reference to any of those words.

What am I missing?

This is all that's visible in the CSV in Excel:

```
150,4,setosa,versicolor,virginica
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,0
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,0
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,0
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,0
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,0
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,0
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,0
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,0
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,0
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,0
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,0
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,0
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,0
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,0
5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,0
Etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/base.py#L216) for the `datasets.load_iris()` function -- which you can easily do using `datasets.load_iris??` if you're using IPython -- you can see what's going on.  At the last part of the function -- after it's read and processed the `iris.csv` and `iris.rst` files -- you see

```
return Bunch(data=data, target=target,
             target_names=target_names,
             DESCR=fdescr.read(),
             feature_names=['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)',
                            'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])
```

and so those feature names are hardcoded in the function, not in the `csv`.

Comment: When I try to use the "??" syntax in Ipython I get this:`code`iris = datasets.load_iris()??
  File "<ipython-input-6-6e7f7891866f>", line 1
    iris = datasets.load_iris()??
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3213857: Try `datasets.load_iris??`, not `iris = datasets.load_iris()??`.